# Signing Out of Google Sign In

Tags: google-oauth

I have a site that users can use their Google accounts to authetnicate with.  The sign out page is not working, though.  I automatically get signed in when I revisit the login page.  Can anyone tell me why my page is not signing Google users out?

https://bluezero.xyz/logout.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to nest the call to `getAuthInstance()` within `init()`'s Promise, a la:

```
function signOut() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        gapi.auth2.init().then(function(){ /// THIS WAS THE SOLUTION HERE
            var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            auth2.signOut().then(function(){
                console.log("User is logged out");
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Google's recommended method did not work:

```
// FROM GOOGLE (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#sign_out_a_user)
function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () { // THIS FAILED BECAUSE getAuthInstance() HADN'T COMPLETED
        console.log('User signed out.');
    });
}
```